# Count precent of lines that pass AWK filter?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file (my_file) and want to count how many values in column 11 have value < .05:

I try:

```
echo $($(cat my_file | cut -f 11 | awk '$1 < 5E-2'  | wc -l) / $(cat my_file | cut -f 11 |  wc -l))
```

I get `1158532: command not found`

Could anyone please help me see where I am wrong?

Comment: can edit your question and include a text  sample of the contents of `my_file`?

Comment: `echo $(...)` is a very unusual construction.  You might as well just run the command.  There's really no point in collection the output just to pass it to `echo`.  It changes whitespace, but otherwise does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: _help me see where I am wrong_ : The outer `$(...)` means: _Take the standard output of what's inside (i.e. the output from `wc`) and execute this as command`. Since your `wc` outputs the number 1158532, you ask the shell to run a command named `1158532`, and since such a command does not exist, you get the error message.

Comment: I also don't understand, what the lone slash (`/`) is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the string:

```
$(cat my_file | cut -f 11 | awk '$1 < 5E-2' | wc -l)
```

The `$()` construct is a "command substitution".  The commands inside `$()` are executed and produce some output.  That output is then executed as a command.  If the pipelie produces the output "1158532", then `bash` will attempt to execute that string as a command.  But there is no command `1158532` in your PATH, so you get the error message that you see.  You really should just do this whole thing in `awk` with something like:

```
awk '$11 < 0.05 {c++} END {printf "%2.2f%%\n", 100.0 * c / NR}' my_file
```

To help understand why your command does not work, it might help to consider "fixing" it to be:

```
expr "$( cat my_file | cut -f 11 | awk '$1 < 5E-2'  | wc -l)" / "$(cat my_file | cut -f 11 |  wc -l)"
```

but notice that this will produce `0` or `1`, since the arithmetic is not floating point, but is integers.  You could get floating point values by running the data through `bc` with:

```
echo "$( cat my_file | cut -f 11 | awk '$1 < 5E-2'  | wc -l)" / "$(cat my_file | cut -f 11 |  wc -l)" | bc -l
```

Note that all of these UUOC should be removed (eg, with `< my_file cut -f 11`) and `cut | awk` is generally an anti-pattern.  Just do the whole thing in `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to handle this all via `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {cnt=0} { if ($11<.05) cnt+=1 } END {printf "%2.2f%%\n", cnt/NR*100}' my_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only `awk`:

```
awk '$11 < 0.05 {c++} END {print c}' my_file
```

Comment: This counts the lines, but does not present the result as a percentage.

Comment: This works differently if the fields contain spaces (it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to transform parts of your command into shorter equivalents:

```
cat my_file | cut -f 11 | wc -l
cat my_file | wc -l
wc -l < my_file

cat my_file | cut -f 11 | awk '$1 < 5E-2' | wc -l
cat my_file | awk -F'\t' '$11 < 5E-2' | wc -l
awk -F'\t' '$11 < 5E-2' my_file | wc -l
awk -F'\t' '$11 < 5E-2 {c++} END {print c}' my_file
```

To divide the two results:

```
awk -F'\t' '$11 < 5E-2 {c++} END {print c/NR}' my_file
0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

> Count precent of lines that pass AWK filter?

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
0.01
0.03
0.05
0.07
0.09
```

then

```
awk '{cnt+=$1<0.05}END{print cnt/NR*100 "%"}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
40%
```

Explanation: comparison gives 0 or 1, so I use `+=` which increase by 0 when condition not met and increase by 1 when condition holds. After all lines processed I compute percentage simply by dividing cnt by NR (which is inside END is number of all lines) and multiply by `100`. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that `file.txt` has no less than 1 line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '
BEGIN {        ___=((_+=++_+_)*_+(\
           __=_*_+—-_) )^-!(_ -= _) 
} {  _+=+($__)<___ 
} END {

    printf("\n\n\tFilter hit rate :: %.*f %% ( %\47.f / %\47.f )"\
           " \n\n\t%*sFile :: %-.*s \n\n",
                    ___=__--,__*_*__/(__=NR),_,__,
             ___,____,_^=_*=_+=_^=_<_, FILENAME) } ' my_file
```

|

```
Filter hit rate :: 0.04415484271 % ( 3,588 / 8,125,949 )   

           File :: myfile
```